# Como guardar um array em sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html5

Preciso guardar em uma sessionStorage um array de strings mas não sei como.

Comment: Então preciso guardar em um unico session Storage mais de um dado

Comment: Recupera o array, modifica e salva com a mesma chave.